# Win32 synchronization

Tags: windows

I am trying to write an application (console based),in which one thread reads information from console and another thread prints the same information back to console.

I am stuck in implementing the synchronization logic .

Can anyone refer me some samples.

john

Comment: In what language?  With what library?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean c++, you can find sample here:

[Using Critical Section Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686908%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)